# Cannot find classes in a package using Class.forName()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, reflection, jvm, cucumber

Using Java I am implementing a Page Factory object for selenium testing that takes the name of a page object and instantiates it through reflection for use by Cucumber step definitions. The problem I am having is that the code below cannot find the declared class. Both the object `PageFactory` which contains this code and the page object `LoginPage` reside in a package called `pages`.

```
 /**
 * This method take a string containing a Page Object class name (case-sensitive) and returns an instance of the Page Object.
 * This allows us to operate on pages without knowing they exist when we write step definitions.
 * @param choice String
 * @return Page Object cast as a Page
 */
public static Page getPage(String choice) {
    Page entity = null;

    try {
        entity = (Page) Class.forName(choice).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

I receive a stack trace with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LoginPage` as the beginning of the error. If I change the entity creation to the following code, then it works.

```
        private static String packageName = "pages";
        entity = (Page) Class.forName(packageName + "." + choice).newInstance();
```

The problem is that I want to organize my pages. When I create `pages.mywebsite` and place `LoginPage` within that, `PageFactory` won't know where to find the file.

Leaving aside the problem that I could have two namespaces `pages.mywebsite` and `pages.myotherwebsite` that both have a `LoginPage` object, how can I find the files I want without declaring the exact package, and just say "Look in this package and the ones below for the class"?

Comment: I suppose, `Page.forName(…)` is supposed to be `Class.forName(…)`? Besides that, who do you expect to decide whether `pages.mywebsite.LoginPage` or `pages.myotherwebsite.LoginPage` is the right class? A magic unicorn?

Comment: Edited the code above. I actually created my own forName() methods to try to solve my problem. But for the purpose of this discussion, I am back to using the default ones.

As for who is deciding, I'm thinking the solution is to do it by directory structure based on the existing page object is loaded - staying at the same level.

Comment: So… `existingPage.getClass().getPackage().getName()+'.'+choice` or am I missing something?

Comment: There is no existing page object. I had Page.forName() because I had a static forName() function I had created. I have a circular reference problem. I can't instantiate the page object until I know the package, and I can't know the package until I create the page object.

The idea is other people will create page objects and put them in folders in the `pages` package, but I won't know about them or their folder structure. Perhaps I should be doing this a different way?

Comment: In your previous comment you said “*I'm thinking the solution is to do it by directory structure based on the existing page object is loaded - staying at the same level*”, so I’m surprised that you are now saying there is no existing page object and well, if there is no existing page object than what does “staying at the same level” mean? The same as *what*?

Comment: Ok, so let's say I have a package called `pages`, and a sub folder called `my_sub_pages`. In `pages` I have an object, `myFirstPage`. In the subfolder I have two objects, `mySecondPage` and `myThirdPage`. I have a `PageManager` object that is a singleton that holds a static `Page` reference pointing to `myFirstPage`. Using that, I want to find `myThirdPage`, instantiate it and point my `PageManager` `Page` reference to it.

Comment: It seems you are mixing up the terms *object* and *class*. But neither really fits to your explanation. You don’t have objects in folders and you don’t have a reference pointing to a class. But regardless of that, the fundamental problem still is the same as addressed in my first comment: who is supposed to know that the item to find is in “a sub folder called my_sub_pages”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem. I moved the reflection into a `findPageInPackage` method, and the called it recursively to search through directories.

Full code here: https://github.com/dougnoel/sentinel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dougnoel/sentinel/pages/PageFactory.java

```
/**
 * Returns a page object if it exists in the package searched.
 * @param pageName String the name of the page object class to instantiate
 * @param packageName String the name of the package to search
 * @return Page the page object if it exists, otherwise null
 */
private static Page findPageInPackage(String pageName, String packageName) {
    Page page = null;
    try {
        page = (Page) Class.forName(packageName + "." + pageName).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        log.trace("{}.{} Page Object creation failed.", packageName, pageName);
        log.trace("java.lang.InstantiationException: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        log.trace("{}.{} Page Object creation failed.", packageName, pageName);
        log.trace("java.lang.IllegalAccessException: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.trace("{}.{} Page Object creation failed.", packageName, pageName);
        log.trace("java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return page;
}

/**
 * Returns the Page Object for the page name. This allows us to operate on pages
 * without knowing they exist when we write step definitions.
 * <p>
 * Searches any optional page object packages set with the pageObjectPackages system property, and 
 * then searches the defaultPackageName value.
 * <p>
 * <b>Example:</b>
 * <p>
 * <code>System.setProperty("pageObjectPackages", "pages.SharedComponent,pages.UserAdminTool");</code>
 * 
 * @param pageName String the name of the page in
 *                 <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case">Pascal
 *                 case</a>
 * @return Page the specific page object cast as a generic page object
 * @throws PageNotFoundException if page could not be built or retrieved.
 * @throws ConfigurationNotFoundException if the value is not found in the configuration file
 */
public static Page buildOrRetrievePage(String pageName) throws PageNotFoundException, ConfigurationNotFoundException {
    Page page = pages.get(pageName);
    final String errorMessage = "The page you want to test could not be built. At least one Page object package is required to run a test. Please add a pageObjectPackages property to your conf/sentinel.yml configuration file and try again.";
    if (page != null) {
        return page;
    } else {
        if (pageObjectPackagesList == null) {
            pageObjectPackagesList = ConfigurationManager.getPageObjectPackageList();
            if(pageObjectPackagesList == null) {
                throw new PageNotFoundException(errorMessage);
            }
        }

        for (String pageObjectPackage : pageObjectPackagesList) {
            log.trace("pageObjectPackage: " + pageObjectPackage);
            page = findPageInPackage(pageName, pageObjectPackage);
            if (page != null) {
                break; // If we have a page object, stop searching.
            }
        }
    }
    if(page == null) {
        throw new PageNotFoundException(errorMessage);
    }
    pages.put(pageName, page);
    return page;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the classpath using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`, split it around `File.pathSeparator`, and scan the results using [FileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

Comment: I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks!